# tesseract command not working and giving file error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ocr, tesseract, lstm

I have installed tesseract version 4.0 in ubuntu.
I am able to perform all the actions of tesseract using Tesseract CLI like simple OCR text generation.
I want to train the LSTM.
I read this [article](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00#training-from-scratch) and tried to run the following command directly on terminal after isntalling Tesseract from Build.

```
mkdir -p ~/tesstutorial/engoutput
training/lstmtraining --debug_interval 100 \
  --traineddata ~/tesstutorial/engtrain/eng/eng.traineddata \
  --net_spec '[1,36,0,1 Ct3,3,16 Mp3,3 Lfys48 Lfx96 Lrx96 Lfx256 O1c111]' \
  --model_output ~/tesstutorial/engoutput/base --learning_rate 20e-4 \
  --train_listfile ~/tesstutorial/engtrain/eng.training_files.txt \
  --eval_listfile ~/tesstutorial/engeval/eng.training_files.txt \
  --max_iterations 5000 &>~/tesstutorial/engoutput/basetrain.log
```

Althoguh it created the engouput directory.

Current path was pointed to SRC directory of tesseract. 
Get the following error :

> bash: training/lstmtraining: No such file or directory

Running as

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by following code
Create Training Data First

```
cd ~/tesseract-ocr/src
      training/tesstrain.sh   \
       --fonts_dir /usr/share/fonts/ \
      --lang eng   \
      --linedata_only \
      --noextract_font_properties \
      --exposures "0"    \
      --langdata_dir /home/shan/langdata_lstm \
      --output_dir /home/shan/tesstutorial/engtrain  \
      --tessdata_dir /home/shan/tesseract-ocr/tessdata \
      --fontlist "Arial"

  sudo chmod -R 777 /home/shan/tesstutorial/engtrain
```

Then LSTM Model

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/shan/tesstutorial/
cd ~/tesseract-ocr/src/
training/lstmtraining --stop_training \
  --continue_from ~/tesstutorial/engoutput/base_checkpoint \
  --traineddata ~/tesstutorial/engtrain/eng/eng.traineddata \
  --model_output ~/tesstutorial/engoutput/eng.traineddata


sudo chmod -R 777 ~/tesstutorial
cd ~/tesseract-ocr/src/
training/lstmtraining --debug_interval 100   \
--traineddata ~/tesstutorial/engtrain/eng/eng.traineddata   \
--net_spec '[1,36,0,1 Ct3,3,16 Mp3,3 Lfys48 Lfx96 Lrx96 Lfx256 O1c111]'   \
--model_output ~/tesstutorial/engoutput/base --learning_rate 20e-4   \
--train_listfile ~/tesstutorial/engtrain/eng.training_files.txt   \
--max_iterations 5000 &>~/tesstutorial/engoutput/basetrain.log
```